# Rails server 'require_relative' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the rails server to work but run into this issue.

```
bin/rails:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /vagrant/config/boot (LoadError)
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

And the bin/rails file shows this

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

Not sure what I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like file is not exists by path: `/vagrant/config/boot.rb`. Log in to Vagrant VM through SSH and check it.